# VBA to colour cells if cell value matches

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA and have this script which searches for the Array "VC" and changes the matching cells within the range by colouring them red.

My problem is I need to change the criteria from -MyArr = Array("VC") to instead search column A and find any corresponding matches in the same row within the range "B2:D20" then colour the matches red as the below script does.

As per the below script I don't want a case sensitive search and am using XLpart to include partial matches. Please help, thanks

```
Sub Mark_cells_in_column()
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim MyArr As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim I As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    MyArr = Array("VC")
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:d20")
        For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
             Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                    Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next I
    End With
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Sample data:

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be done in VBA instead of with built-in tools like Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Yes, my reason is because VBA is faster than conditional formatting. The front end of my application is already at capacity with a lot of array formulas and I think if I added conditional formatting it would render the application unusable. I also have issues with conditional formatting rules being dupliucated when a user copies and pastes cells within the conditional formating range...before I know it I will have hundreds of duplicated conditional formatting rules   :)

Comment: I'm afraid you have it *absolutely backwards*.  Built-in functionality such as Conditional Formatting is built in far more efficient coding languages than VBA, and are vigorously tested by teams of professionals at multi-billion dollar companies, therefore when used properly, are exponentially more efficient and reliable than custom written VBA.  As for your concern of cells being *copied* repeatedly: this would be a valid concern if you individually formatted a cell and then copied it. (That makes "two copies" of the format.)  ...

Comment: @ashleedawg, I experienced worksheets growing/going out of control due to conditional formatting spreading, too. So I tend to use it as less as I can.

Comment: @DisplayName Funny, I tend to lean towards Conditional Formatting as much as possible and find it more efficient than other alternatives.  That being said, I can't currently locate the pages I know I've seen recommending Conditional Formatting to speed up Excel and reduce file size, so for now I retract (part) of my earlier comments.  (Of course the bottom line at the end of the day is [in my opinion]:  the *"correct"* method is *"whichever gets the job done"* and will vary quite a bit from case to case!)

Comment: @ashleedawg holy words

Comment: @DisplayName yup

Comment: I agree with that approach @ashleedawg "Whichever gets the job done." In regards to using conditional formatting I guess I have been bitten too many times and had too clean up the mess created when the rules multiply. Perhaps I am missing something to prevent this from happening but I have developed a preference for VBA. I appreciate the input from you all.

Comment: @shano I appreciate the feedback too.  One of these reasons I enjoy answering questions on here is because **I'm** always learning at the same time. (That being said I'm a big believer that #1 most important skill for programming is *Google Search Skills*.  There should be a  class!)  ... The beautiful thing with Excel/Access/Office/VBA is that there's "10 ways to do most anything"...  All completely different but none incorrect.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will go through all cells in column A, split each cell value (comma-delimited) into separate items, and search for each item in the same row (case insensitive), through columns B to D

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MarkCellsInColumns()
    Dim arr As Variant, r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, f As Range, vals As Variant

    arr = Sheet1.UsedRange

    With Sheet1.UsedRange
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If Not IsError(arr(r, 1)) Then
                If Len(arr(r, 1)) > 0 Then

                    vals = Split(arr(r, 1), ",")        'check each value in one cell
                    For i = 0 To UBound(vals)
                        For c = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)     'check all columns on same row
                            If LCase(Trim$(vals(i))) = LCase(Trim$(arr(r, c))) Then
                                If f Is Nothing Then
                                    Set f = .Cells(r, c)
                                Else
                                    Set f = Union(f, .Cells(r, c))  'union of found cells
                                End If
                                f.Select
                            End If
                        Next c
                    Next i

                End If
            End If
        Next r
        If Not f Is Nothing Then f.Interior.Color = vbRed   'color all in one operation
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks Paul, its not quite exactly what I wanted. Let me try and explain better with an example. What I am trying to do is look at the value of A1 and if range B1:D1 has the same value as A1 then highlight the cell that matches A1. This criteria should loop through each row down to row A20. A1 could contain several values such as "RT, VC, BB, TR" I would want the VBA to check each of those values within each cell for example if B1 value was "BB" the criteria is met and that cell would be highlighted red. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Another question: let's say you have `A1="RT, VC, BB, TR"`. You want to look for each value only in B1, C1, and D1? or all the rows in columns B, C, and D?

Comment: Hi Paul, I will try and update my original post to give more detail as expressed above. Regarding your last question, I would only want to look at B1, C1 & D1. All rows must be checked based on their corresponding value in column A. for example A5 is used to determine B5, C5 & D5 only, then move onto the next row... until row 20. Also each value in column A is sperated by a "," and a space (If there is more than one value.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know if there are any issues

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much Paul, this works perfectly. I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A20")
        For Each cell2 In cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 3)
            If Instr(cell.Value, cell2.Value) > 0 Then cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Next
    Next 
End Sub
```

Or

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("B:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If Instr(.Cells(cell.Row,1).Value, cell.Value) > 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Next
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice and simple!

Comment: @QHarr, thanks. My code is taylored to OP’s example where there are no possible substrings mismatches. Of course it can be easily enhanced to handle that case, too.

Comment: I was busy writing a regex and then your answer popped up. It was a "duh" moment......

Comment: @QHarr & DisplayName - what a coincidence you're both here, I was just querying "who has all the tag badges iin (VBA,Excel,Excel-VBA) and has answered the most related questions this year?"....  And the two of you are pretty much tied for 1st ([See the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/834388/who-has-badges-for-excel-vba-excel-vba-and-answers-the-most-related-questions))  Stats are as up to Monday on SEDE so the balance could have tipped since then

Comment: @QHarr, I envy you for being able to use RegExp: I have never been bold (and smart) enough to face it!

Comment: @ashleedawg, I guess it’s QHarr!

Comment: morning or rather evening @ashleedawg. I can't compete with the speed provided or quality of DisplayName's answers but I will continue plodding through what I can. Stats are up for what on SEDE Monday? P.s. my Regex Fu is weak.

Comment: @QHarr seems to me you said something similar about "competing" with me, and then proceeded to blow me away at a 2:1 answer rate since then...  Careful DsiplayName, he's just trying to get you to drop your guard.

Comment: @ashleedawg, I know that! I’ll be watching out!